# WSGI servers for Python 3 (PEP 3333)

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi

What WSGI servers are available for Python 3 and [PEP 3333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by Gabriel, Apache/mod_wsgi 3.X supports Python 3. Other options are [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) WSGI server and [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/).

Comment: Just be aware that if using Python 3.2, you need to use mod_wsgi 4.X source code, currently from mod_wsgi source code repository.

Answer (score 8):

## Waitress

[Waitress](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/) is meant to be a production-quality pure-Python WSGI server with very acceptable performance. It has no dependencies except ones which live in the Python standard library. It runs on CPython on Unix and Windows under Python 2.6+ and Python 3.2. It is also known to run on PyPy 1.6.0 on UNIX. It supports HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1.

Here is a quote from their website on why they wrote it:

> ### Why?
>
> At the time of the release of Waitress, there are already many pure-Python WSGI servers. Why would we need another?
>
> Waitress is meant to be useful to web framework authors who require broad platform support. It's neither the fastest nor the fanciest WSGI server available but using it helps eliminate the N-by-M documentation burden (e.g. production vs. deployment, Windows vs. Unix, Python 3 vs. Python 2, PyPy vs. CPython) and resulting user confusion imposed by spotty platform support of the current (2012-ish) crop of WSGI servers. For example, gunicorn is great, but doesn't run on Windows. paste.httpserver is perfectly serviceable, but doesn't run under Python 3 and has no dedicated tests suite that would allow someone who did a Python 3 port to know it worked after a port was completed. wsgiref works fine under most any Python, but it's a little slow and it's not recommended for production use as it's single-threaded and has not been audited for security issues.
>
> At the time of this writing, some existing WSGI servers already claim wide platform support and have serviceable test suites. The CherryPy WSGI server, for example, targets Python 2 and Python 3 and it can run on UNIX or Windows. However, it is not distributed separately from its eponymous web framework, and requiring a non-CherryPy web framework to depend on the CherryPy web framework distribution simply for its server component is awkward. The test suite of the CherryPy server also depends on the CherryPy web framework, so even if we forked its server component into a separate distribution, we would have still needed to backfill for all of its tests. The CherryPy team has started work on Cheroot, which should solve this problem, however.
>
> Waitress is a fork of the WSGI-related components which existed in zope.server. zope.server had passable framework-independent test coverage out of the box, and a good bit more coverage was added during the fork. zope.server has existed in one form or another since about 2001, and has seen production usage since then, so Waitress is not exactly "another" server, it's more a repackaging of an old one that was already known to work fairly well.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, the latest version of mod_wsgi (3.3) is compatible with Python 3 according to PEP 3333:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/

> "The original WSGI specification (PEP 333) only supports Python 2.X.
>   There is support in mod_wsgi for Python 3.X which is based on guesses
>   as to what the WSGI specification would look like for Python 3.X. The
>   new WSGI specification (PEP 3333) has finally now been accepted and
>   although some tweaks need to be made to mod_wsgi to make it more
>   strict, if you write your Python 3 WSGI application according to PEP
>   3333, it will work perfectly fine on mod_wsgi. If you wish to
>   experiment with Python 3.X, you will need to use Python 3.1 or later."

Answer (score 2):

I like the [Rocket Web server](https://launchpad.net/rocket), particular because it is itself written in python.  It also has an API for creating other kinds of servers.  I was able to adapt it into an XMLRPC server with a minimal amount of effort.

Answer (score 1):

[wsgiref](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/wsgiref.html), which is a part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

[Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) supports PEP333 since version 3.0. Originally a Ruby app server, it now officially supports Python. Amongst the features are:

- Integrates directly into the web server (similar to how mod_wsgi works) but runs all app processes outside the web server.
- Apache and Nginx support.
- Evented internal I/O architecture.
- Multiprocess application worker I/O architecture. Phusion Passenger buffers all input and output in order to protect applications from slow clients.
- Output buffering with real-time flushing.
- Dynamic spawning and stopping of worker processes based on traffic.
- Automatic user switching, a convenient security feature.
- Rolling restarts.

Phusion Passenger is currently used by large parties like New York Times, AirBnB, Pixar, Symantec, etc.

Comment: Please stop pitching, the question states very clearly Python3 and PEP 3333.

Comment: And I state very clearly that Phusion Passenger supports Python 3 and PEP 3333, which is exactly what the question was about.

Answer (score 0):

### `bjoern`: Fast And Ultra-Lightweight HTTP/1.1 WSGI Server

Quoting the [README](https://github.com/jonashaag/bjoern/blob/master/README.rst):

> #### Why It's Cool
>
> `bjoern` is the fastest, smallest and most lightweight WSGI server out there, featuring
>
> - ~ 1000 lines of C code
> - Memory footprint ~ 600KB
> - Python 2 and Python 3 support
> - Single-threaded and without coroutines or other crap
> - Can bind to TCP host:port addresses and Unix sockets
> - Full persistent connection (*"keep-alive"*) support in both HTTP/1.0 and 1.1, including support for HTTP/1.1 chunked responses

If you take a look at WSGI server benchmarks on the web (e.g. [A Performance Analysis of Python WSGI Servers](https://www.appdynamics.com/blog/engineering/a-performance-analysis-of-python-wsgi-servers-part-2/)), the performance boost is indeed astounishing:

[image]

#### How to install

```
$ pip install bjoern
```

#### Prerequisites

You will need `gcc` and `libev` packages to be installed before building `bjoern`:

- **Debian/Ubuntu**:

  ```
  $ sudo apt install build-essential
  $ sudo apt install libev-dev
  ```
- **RHEL/CentOS**:

  ```
  $ sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
  $ sudo yum install libev-devel
  ```
- **Fedora**:

  ```
  $ dnf groupinstall 'Development Tools'
  $ sudo dnf install libev-devel
  ```
- **MacOS**:

  Install XCode from App Store to get `gcc`; for `libev`, either build from source or install vie Homebrew:

  ```
  $ brew install libev
  ```
- **Windows**

  Unfortunately, Windows is not supported because `libev` is not available.

### `meinheld`: a high performance asynchronous WSGI Web Server (based on picoev)

Quoting the [official site](https://meinheld.org/):

> Meinheld is a high-performance WSGI-compliant web server that takes advantage of greenlet and picoev to enable asynchronous network I/O in a light-weight manner.

Similar to `bjoern`, `meinheld` is mostly written in C for speed and is built around a high-performance event library ([`picoev`](https://github.com/kazuho/picoev/) vs `libev` by `bjoern`). Because of that, you'll also need to have GCC installed in order to build `meinheld`'s C extension. Installable on Linux, MacOS and FreeBSD.

#### Installation

```
$ pip install meinheld
```